# Find next element with a given class, regardless of where it appears in the DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out something which I believe should be relatively simple.

**I need to get the next occurrence of a class (div.content), which could appear anwhere in the DOM**

Below is some simplified markup which represents what I have:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Example content #1    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Example content #2    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Example content #1    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Example content #2    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Showing the next `content` div within a given `container` works fine, the problem comes when I try to get from the **last** `content` div in a `container` to the **first** `content` div  in the next `container`.

A couple of important points:-

- By default, **only the first** `content` div is visible, the rest are hidden, though I need a solution that would work if for instance the second `content` div in the fourth `container` is visible.
- Only one `content` div will ever be visible.

The only solution I've managed to come up with so far seems extremely cumbersome, although it *does* work.

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $theContent = $(this).parent('.content');
    $theContent.hide();

    if ($theContent.next('.content').length) {
        $theContent.next('.content').show();
    } else if ($theContent.parent('.container').next('.container')
        .children('.content').length
    ) {
        $theContent.parent('.container').next('.container')
            .children('.content:first').show();
    } else {
        // reached the end or something went wrong
    }
});
```

The major downside to this is that it relies on having the above DOM structure, I'd convinced myself that a method would exist for selecting the next element with a given class, regardless of where it appeared in the DOM.

**Ideally I'd like a solution which doesn't rely on any given DOM structure, if that's not possible, any alternative solutions would be helpful!**

[Here's a fiddle with the above example](http://jsfiddle.net/MgP6N/2/)

Sorry for the long-winded question!

Comment: I really didn't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. In a nutshell, I want to show the next element with a given class when an anchor is clicked, ideally regardless of where it appears in the dom tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is indeed a very simple task. By passing a selector to jQuery's `index()` method, you're able to get the index of the current element, relative to its collection:

```
var idx = $theContent.index('div.content') + 1;
```

Then the `content` div can be targeted directly:

```
$('div.content').eq(idx).show();
```

Comment: This is a nice solution.  I will see about implementing that myself!

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(function() {
    var i = 1;
    jQuery('.content').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('content-' + i);
        i++;

        jQuery(this).find('a.next').bind('click', function() {
            toggleContentDivs(jQuery(this).parent());
        }); 
    });
});

function toggleContentDivs(oContentDiv)
{
    var nextVisible   = false,
        setVisibility = false;

    jQuery('.content').each(function() {
        if (oContentDiv.attr('class') == jQuery(this).attr('class')) {
            nextVisible = true;
            jQuery(this).hide();
        } else if (nextVisible == true) {
            jQuery(this).show();
            nextVisible   = false;
            setVisibility = true;
        } else {
            jQuery(this).hide();
        }
    });
    // it must have been the last .content element
    if (setVisibility == false) { 
        jQuery('.content:first').show();
    }
}
```

Only DOM dependency with the existing code, is a.next must be an immediate child of .content.

Working jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SZhAr/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out a simpler (*less verbose*) way to write it is exactly how you had it minus the function arguments:

```
$theContent.parent().next().length
```

EDIT 2:

I tried all of my solutions extensively but they were flawed.  In short I think you pretty have the simplest way of doing it.  Unless maybe a jQuery expert could chime in on this and show us a better way.

Here's my last proposal:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    $theContent = $(this).parent('.content');
    $theContent.hide(10, function() {
        if (!$theContent.next('.content').length) {
            $theContent.parent('.container').next()
                .find('.content:first').show();
        } else {
            $theContent.next('.content').show();
        }
    });
});
```

The ideal solution would be to use `closest()`, but the problem is that it's not behaving the way I expected because of their separation by containers.  In jQuery's example they use an unordered list.  Well yeah, this is much easier because you can distinguish between node types (e.g. `li` vs `ul`) and simply do `.next('li')`.  Here you are using all `div`s.  And for some reason `.closest('.content')` doesn't work once the end of the first container is reached!

Comment: +1 - I don't know what it is, when I started this I thought it would be alot simpler, I convinced myself that a method would exist for selecting the next given element regardless or where it appeared in the dom tree, ahh well! Thanks for the answer

Comment: You're welcome.  I too am always looking for shorter ways to write JavaScript code using the jQuery library.  Let me know if you find anything to correct!

Answer (score -1):

how about this:

```
if ($theContent.next('.content').length) {
   $theContent.next('.content').show();
} else if ($theContent.parent('.container').next('.container').children('.content').length) {
   $theContent.parent('.container').next('.container').children('.content:first').show();
} else {
   $('.content:first').show();
   //alert('Reached the end or something went wrong!');
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MgP6N/3/)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, it's identical except it shows the first `content` div again once it reaches the end