# jQuery Find Next Occurrence in DOM by Classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

using jQuery I need to dynamically find the next occurrence of a given element in the DOM by its class name regardless of the DOM structure. This means the elements in question could be scattered at random within the DOM with no common parent element. Additional elements could be added to the DOM at any time post page load so I need to avoid getting a list of the elements on page load and iterating through that. Any ideas?

Comment: post your html please? or ask with some sample code

Comment: you could just refer to the respective element with specific class name and call `.next(<class name>)` to get the next element with similiar class name . **REF:http://api.jquery.com/next/**

Comment: Thats right. `.next('class_name')` would just do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show next element with a given class, regardless of where it appears in the DOM tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848072/show-next-element-with-a-given-class-regardless-of-where-it-appears-in-the-dom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the current elements' `index()`, passing the collections' selector, and add 1 to get the next occurrence:

```
var index = $('div.example:first').index('div.example') + 1;
var $next = $('div.example').eq(index);
```

I had the same **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848072/show-next-element-with-a-given-class-regardless-of-where-it-appears-in-the-dom)** a while back

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdH25/6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var givenElement =$('.myClass').eq(0);


//Next Occ
givenElement.next('.myClass')
```

**DEMO :** http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Q9835/3/

Comment: Only works if the next occurrence is always the next immediate sibling

Comment: You are so right. i will revise it

Answer (score 0):

*Try* ,

```
console.log($("body").find(".yourclassname"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.nextAll()` with `:first` this way:

```
$('.cls').nextAll('.cls:first')
```

where `.cls` is your class name of your dom elem.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ung2/)

#### [Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ung2/2/)

Comment: This only works if next occurrences are always sibling elements, which is not the case

Comment: @billyonecan yes you are correct as OP has not posted any markup so i suggested this.

Comment: *"I need to dynamically find the next occurrence of a given element in the DOM by its class name regardless of the DOM structure"*